# Tell whether the template argument is a struct

Tags: d, traits

How can I make a template that tells whether the argument is a struct or not? I.e. how to make the following code run without an error:

```
struct X { int a; }
static assert(isStruct!X);
static assert(!isStruct!int);
```

Comment: If you need to distinguish between basic type and class, struct you can use std.traits. http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#isAggregateType

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in distinguish structs. There are stuff for classes in traits but not for structs, and that was confusing. That's why I overlooked `is`, it's not in the traits module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`is`](http://dlang.org/expression.html#IsExpression) expression.

```d
struct X { int a; }
static assert(is(X == struct));
static assert(!is(int == struct));
```

But if you really want a template:

```d
template isStruct(T)
{
    enum bool isStruct = is(T == struct);
}
```